# UITabBar background image not showing properly

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitabbar

I made custom UITabBar class and tried to set background image.

```
tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "my_image")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
```

I set the image file name to my_image@2x and image file is 640*98

I run on iPhone6 simulator and it seems the image is not wide enough like
Google's "C" is repeated on sample below

[image]

Im I using wrong image size or is something else is wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just redraw the image:

```
var image = UIImage(named: "my_image")
if let image = image {
    var centerImage: Bool = false
    var resizeImage: UIImage?
    let size = CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 98)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    if centerImage {
        //if you want to center image, use this code
        image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (size.width-image.size.width)/2, y: 0), size: image.size))
    }
    else {
        //stretch image
        image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
    }
    resizeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    tabBar.backgroundImage = resizeImage.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
}
```