# UITabbar Background Image Repeats Itself

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

In my application, i tried to set UITabbar background image as a subview, however, background image gets repeated in UITabbar, below is my code to set the background image  in UITabbar

```
    tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "Pannel.png")
    self.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.tabBar.autoresizesSubviews = false;
    self.tabBar.clipsToBounds = true[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

. Here is my output of tabbar image

[image]

**2nd Approach**

Add view as SubView

```
    let bgView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Pannel.png"))
    bgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.tabBar.frame.origin.y - 35, width: self.tabBar.frame.width , height: 64)
    self.view.addSubview(bgView)
```

Below is my output of 2nd approach

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to resizing the image to tab bar size or you can add an imageView to tab bar as subView, then use image in that imageView. Just try with below code:

```
let bgView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "imageName"))
bgView.frame = self.tabBar.bounds
self.tabBar.addSubview(bgView)
self.tabBar.sendSubview(toBack: bgView)
```

Comment: i have tried as subview but it's hiding my tabbar buttons

Comment: May be this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38603207/uitabbar-background-image-not-showing-properly?rq=1

Comment: is it helpful above link?

Comment: Yes, it was for me. Thanks! This is the correct answer, please accept it.